# Escaping %E in Python strings

Tags: python, sql, pandas, ipython

Hi I have a query in triple quotes

```
f_name = "'Pra_%'"
df = cp.sql("""SELECT first_name, last_name,  FROM Students
               WHERE first_name LIKE %s
               AND last_name LIKE '%Elephant%'
           """ % (f_name))
```

Expecting the query to pick the value from `f_name` and replace the `%s` in the `WHERE` clause.

Received the following error:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-6544d0eca4d1> in <module>()
   3 WHERE first_name LIKE %s
   4 AND last_name LIKE '%Elephant%'
   ---> 5 """ % (f_name))

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I guess it is treating the `%E` in `%Elephant%` as Float and expecting an argument. It works when there is no second condition (`AND last_name LIKE '%Elephant%'`) in the `WHERE` clause.

How can I escape it to make it work in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To escape `%`, you need to double it up into `%%`

Comment: This solution works correctly but the one proposed below by **unutbu** is safer to implement.

Answer (score 4):

Protect yourself from [SQL injection](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by avoiding string formatting.
Use parametrized sql everywhere:

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
sql = """SELECT first_name, last_name,  FROM Students
               WHERE first_name LIKE %s
               AND last_name LIKE %s"""
args = ('Pra_%', '%Elephant%')
df = psql.read_sql(sql, conn, params=args)
```

Notice that you don't have to double quote `'Pra_%'`. The database adapter will quote the arguments for you. So using parametrized sql is not only safer, it is also easier.